# Slim & Rails - How to get text and a button on the same line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have the following which displays the button beneath the text;

```
h3 Some text
= link_to 'Some link', @post, class: 'btn btn-green button'
```

How can I display the button after the header text so it all appears on one line?

Answer (score 1):

```
h3 
  | Some text
  = link_to 'Some link', @post, class: 'btn btn-green button'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the button inside your h3 tag you can set its display to inline-block

```
h3 style="display: inline-block" Some text
= link_to 'Some link', @post, class: 'btn btn-green button'
```